# Sort JSONArray Alphabetically (Single Value)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

For example, given input:

```
{
  "values": ["APPLE", "PEAR", "BANANA"] 
}
```

after sorting required output:

```
{
  "values": ["APPLE", "BANANA", "PEAR"] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have specified the programming language. In general, I suggest you to create the object from Json and use a *sort algorithm*.

For example, in Java 8 exists the Gson library. Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation and viceversa.

For example:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
MyObject obj = g.fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class)
```

So, you have a class like this:

```
public class MyObject {

    List<String> values;

    public MyObject {
         this.values = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //Get values sorted
    public ArrayList<String> getValuesSorted() {         
         Collections.sort(this.values);         
         return this.values;     
    } 
}
```

The method `getValuesSorted` returns the array sorted.

Comment: What would you do for PHP language? for Python? for JavaScript?

Comment: In JS/TS there is the module 'JSON' and its method 'parse', in python there is the library 'json' and its method 'load', etc.. Moreover, about the sorting algorithms are already implemented in all languages..

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Language was JAVA, I do apologize 